# PHP: having trouble with JSON and reading into Python

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get an array into JSON so I can read it out correctly into a Python script. I've managed to get the URL to output data but I'm not sure that it's putting out the correct format. I'm getting an 'Invalid encoding, expecting UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.' error when I run it through a JSON Parser.

Here's the result that I'm getting from the URL....

```
[  
{  
  "year":"2016",
  "Month":"Apr",
  "the_days":"16, 29, 30"
},
{  
  "year":"2016",
  "Month":"May",
  "the_days":"13, 27"
},
{  
  "year":"2016",
  "Month":"Jun",
  "the_days":"10, 11, 24"
},
{  
  "year":"2016",
  "Month":"Jul",
  "the_days":"08, 22, 23"
},
{  
  "year":"2016",
  "Month":"Aug",
  "the_days":"06, 20"
},
{  
  "year":"2016",
  "Month":"Sep",
  "the_days":"02, 03, 16, 17, 30"
},
{  
  "year":"2016",
  "Month":"Oct",
  "the_days":"01, 14, 15, 29"
},
{  
  "year":"2016",
  "Month":"Nov",
  "the_days":"25"
},
{  
  "year":"2016",
  "Month":"Dec",
  "the_days":"09, 10, 23, 24"
}
]
```

This is achieved by putting the data into an array like this....

```
$encodeArray = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $encodeArray[] = $row;
}
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

I'm having trouble figuring out what's wrong with this - could do with some help!

Comment: What are you using to convert `$encodeArray` into JSON?

Comment: It goes in a function called available_dates() that has return $encodeArray; ...then I'm doing echo json_encode(available_dates());

Comment: @dazzathedrummer The JSON is valid - whether or not it accurately represents your data structure is another matter but it shouldn't cause a parsing error. However, you're writing that **python** fails to parse this. Couldn't it be an issue in python instead? Maybe you should post that code too and add python tags?

Comment: @dazzathedrummer Call your php script from a browser, via python's `requests` module, via php's `curl` or something else. Check the raw response data *without* trying to parse it as JSON. You might find that there's something unexpected in your data.

Answer (score 0):

**Use `json_encode` function to convert your array to json string in php and print it on page using `echo` statement. So your script can get response**

```
<?php
    $json_arr = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($json_arr,$row);
    }
    echo json_encode($json_arr);
?>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing - I'm getting a json output but with an error - this is causing my Python script to not be able to read from the URL - I'm just wondering if there is anything wrong with the array.

Comment: @dazzathedrummer *"Yes, that's what I'm doing"* Then you should update the code in your question so it reflects the code you're actually running.

Answer (score 0):

It's looking more and more like there is nothing wrong with my array - it's possible that the problem is happening in my Python script that won't decode the json. 
Separate question to follow!